# How to index Django models into whoosh

Tags: python, django, whoosh

I am trying to index my Django models into Whoosh.In this [tutorial](http://whoosh.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#a-quick-introduction) they are simply indexing text using `content` field but how do i index my Django model in such a way ...

My models.py

```
import json
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 


class scrapedData (models.Model):
    """ This a model for scraped data collected by eScraper"""

    productMRP = models.FloatField()                                      # Product MRP
    image_urls = models.TextField()                                       # Images URL's for image pipeline for downloading
    productSite = models.URLField()                                       # Product web-site URL
    productDesc = models.TextField()                                      # Product Description
    image_paths = models.TextField()                                      # Product images path on the local machine
    productImage = models.TextField()                                     # Product image URL's
    productTitle = models.TextField()                                     # Product title
    productPrice = models.FloatField()                                    # Product discounted price
    hasVariants = models.BooleanField()                                   # Product variants like : colors or sizes, True is if product has variants, False otherwise
    productCategory = models.TextField()                                  # Product category
    availability = models.BooleanField()                                  # Product availability ,True if product is in stock, False otherwise
    productSubCategory = models.TextField()                               # Product sub-category
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=3)                             # Product price currency
    productURL = models.URLField(max_length=500)                          # Product page URL
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)                       # Time at which product is updated
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)                   # Time at which product is created


    def product_Image(self):
        """Method to return product images for admin panel"""
        images = ''
        imagePaths = json.loads(self.image_paths)
        for image_path in imagePaths:
            images += '<img src="/images/%s/" height="150" width="150"/>' % image_path            
        return images
    product_Image.allow_tags = True


    def product_URL(self):
        """Method to return product URL for admin panel"""     
        return "<a href=%s>%s<a>"%(self.productURL,self.productTitle)    
    product_URL.allow_tags = True


    class Meta:
        """Meta class to control display Behavior of the Model name """        
        verbose_name_plural = "scrapedData"


class scrapedDataAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """scrapedData admin class"""

    list_display = ('productTitle','productSite','updatedAt','createdAt',
                    'product_URL','product_Image','productMRP','productPrice','currency',
                    'productDesc','productCategory','availability',
                    'hasVariants','productSubCategory','image_paths','image_urls'
                    )

    search_fields = ('productTitle','productSite','productURL','productMRP',
                    'productPrice','productDesc','productCategory','availability',
                    'hasVariants','productSubCategory','image_paths','image_urls'
                    )

    ordering = ('productSite',)


admin.site.register(scrapedData,scrapedDataAdmin)

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have also looked at this [tutorial](http://www.arnebrodowski.de/blog/add-full-text-search-to-your-django-project-with-whoosh.html) but i did not understand how to store index into `Whoosh`. I am new to `Whoosh` can someone please help me...

Comment: Following the tutorial will get you up and running :)

Comment: Are you using [haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/) ?

Comment: No i am not using haystack because it is giving `TemplateDoesNotExist` but in fact it exist because i am able to open search.html .... If you can help me then it will be of great help...

Comment: What do you mean by index model? Index all the fields in models? Do you really want the user to search info in your models by keyword related to whatever field?

Comment: whoosh results seemed kinda unpredictable to me. My 2c: Use Haystack and Solr w/ websolr.com for cheap. Its super simple to set up and you end up w/ a reliable search in the end.

Comment: I am using `haystack`